# Mongo forEach function only performing updates on first row

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

I have a problem when performing an update within a forEach function, it only updates the first row.

Ok, so I am trying to make a query that updates some fields of my documents but I have the following constraints:

1)One of the fields to update has to be looked up in another collection.

2)Based on the value of one of  the fields I have to decide whether update one way or another.

3)Based on the value of one of the fields I have to delete some fields.

The query I am executing is the following:

```
db.events_migration.find({'$or':[{'event.type':'EXBC'},{'event.type':'ENBC'}],'event.value.major':{'$exists':true}}).forEach(function (doc1) {
var doc2 = db.regions.findOne({ 'beaconId.major': doc1.event.value.major,'beaconId.minor':doc1.event.value.minor,'group.uuid':doc1.event.value.uuid });

    if (doc2 != null) {

        doc1.event.value.beacon = doc2._id;
        db.events_migration.save(doc1);

        if(doc1.event.type=='EXBC'){
        db.events_migration.update({'_id':doc1.id}, {$set:{'event.source':'SDK','event.type':'MOB','event.extType':'BCN','event.action':'EXT'},
                                                   $unset:{'event.value.major':'','event.value.minor':'','event.value.uuid':''}});

        }
        else{
        db.events_migration.update({'_id':doc1.id}, {$set:{'event.source':'SDK','event.type':'MOB','event.extType':'BCN','event.action':'ENT'},
                                                       $unset:{'event.value.major':'','event.value.minor':'','event.value.uuid':''}});
        }
}   
});
```

The 1st constraint if working effectively. It looks up for a register in another collection and adds it to doc1:

```
var doc2 = db.regions.findOne({ 'beaconId.major': doc1.event.value.major,'beaconId.minor':doc1.event.value.minor,'group.uuid':doc1.event.value.uuid });
doc1.event.value.beacon = doc2._id;
```

The problem I am having is when performing the update function for constraints 2 and 3, it only updates for the first register and the others are left as they were.

```
db.events_migration.update({'_id':doc1.id}, {$set:{'event.source':'SDK','event.type':'MOB','event.extType':'BCN','event.action':'EXT'},
                                                   $unset:{'event.value.major':'','event.value.minor':'','event.value.uuid':''}});
```

I am somehow new to performing this kind of operations of mongo, so I would appreciate an explanation of why this is happening. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the update query projection.

```
db.events_migration.update({'_id':doc1.id} ...
```

An id of any document should be accessed with the **_id** field. In this case **id** returns `undefined`.

Updating it as follows (**notice underscore**) should solve the problem:

```
db.events_migration.update({'_id':doc1._id} ...
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I got it to work, but I have one more question. I didn't use the multi parameter because I thought that because it was a forEach function it would call the update method for every row, how does this work? If I use the multi param will it be repeting the update for each iteration? Thanks

Comment: Well, my previous answer was misleading, The `multi` argument wasn't a problem in this case. Please extend my apologies. I've updated it. Fill free to ask for more details. I own you for my first answer ;)

Comment: Thanks Daniel!, now it is working like a charm. As I thought and after i checked the logs, the first solution you proposed was performing all the update per iteration, so I was doing it in different scripts. Now it works fine within the forEach function.